# ServiceStack - roles and permissions

Tags: servicestack, role

I'm implementing ServiceStack's Roles and Permissions. I send

```
{"UserName":"JASON1","Permissions":["CanAccess"],"Roles":["Admin"]}
```

via `http://localhost:15465/api/json/reply/AssignRoles`
but i got following error:

```
{
  "AllRoles": [],
  "AllPermissions": [],
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "Invalid Role",
    "Message": "Invalid Role",
    "StackTrace": "[AssignRoles: 3/11/2015 11:12:02 PM]:\n[REQUEST: {UserName:JASON1,Permissions:[CanAccess],Roles:[Admin]}]\nServiceStack.HttpError: Invalid Role\r\n   at ServiceStack.RequiredRoleAttribute.AssertRequiredRoles(IRequest req, String[] requiredRoles)\r\n   at ServiceStack.Auth.AssignRolesService.Post(AssignRoles request)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object )\r\n   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto)",
    "Errors": []
  }
}
```

what will be the solutions and where are some built in roles and permissions? i couldn't find any information? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AssignRolesService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AssignRolesService.cs#L13) shouldn't be called by anyone, by default it can only be called by someone in the `RoleNames.Admin`, i.e. [Admin Role](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#admin-role).

### Use custom Assign Roles Service

You can ignore this default behavior by instead using your own custom Service to assign roles which is just a wrapper around the `IAuthRepository.AssignRoles()` API, e.g:

```
public class CustomRolesService : Service
{
    public IAuthRepository AuthRepo { get; set; }

    public object Post(AssignRoles request)
    {
        var userAuth = AuthRepo.GetUserAuthByUserName(request.UserName);
        if (userAuth == null)
            throw HttpError.NotFound(request.UserName);

        AuthRepo.AssignRoles(userAuth, request.Roles, request.Permissions);

        return new AssignRolesResponse();
    }
}
```

### Master AuthSecret

To help with development ServiceStack also supports [specifying a master password](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#authsecret) with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { AdminAuthSecret = "secretz" });
```

Which then lets you by-pass any protected service with the QueryString:

```
?authsecret=secretz
```

Comment: Ok, i went to the database, granted Admin role to this user. Then he can assign roles & permissions to others. Thanks.