# ServiceStack - Adding additional metadata to the Meta dictionary fields

Tags: authentication, servicestack

i am extending the `UserAuth` to add more fields into it.

i created a new '`User`' table and everything is fine. But the client prefers to stick with the existing '`UserAuth`' table and utilize the 'Adding additional metadata to the Meta dictionary fields'.

I have successfully added `Meta` to responses via a response filter in `AppHost.cs` but i don't know where/how to add Meta to `UserAuth`.

Please enlighten me. A small code sample would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The UserAuth DTO's has a [Meta String Dictionary](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs#L57) you can use to store additional metadata about the user.

This previous answer on [extending ServiceStack UserAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118747/85785) provides an example of using the [rich UserAuth Metadata extension methods](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/0bb072a34e15ad0aa3284da6bdcaddb981771460/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs#L253) to populate the string dictionary with POCO's, e.g:

```
userAuth.Set(new Address { ... });
var address = userAuth.Get<Address>();
```

Comment: I saw that snippet before. Can i ask how/where do i get this userAuth instance? and do i put it into the confige method in AppHost.cs. Thanks.

Comment: @Isley You can get it manually from `IAuthRepository` as a normal dependency at anytime as [shown in the custom service example on the previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33511055/85785). Note you can also cast it to an [IUserAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/IAuthRepository.cs#L19) which most Auth Repos support to get access to a richer API.