# Servicestack Roles Users and Groups

Tags: servicestack

Since roles don't contain permissions. I am a bit confused by the Roles and Permission in ServiceStack. It appears they are really the same thing?  I want to implement a Group, that has roles, that has permissions. Based on the servicestack default implementation I don't think I can extend the provider and get the nested information.

How would i achieve this and still use the authentication attributes.
If i had an attribute

```
[RequiredPermission("CanAccessPerm")] 
That is in Role:HasAccessRole That is in Group:HasAccessGroup
```

I would want to only use perms to determine access at the API level. Then Roles and Groups to determine who has perms. If Roles contained permissions then I could just extend the CredentialsAuthProvider  TryAuthenticate and additionally look at a group table. Is there a way to do this and not rewrite the whole authentication?

Edit 12/12
I am using
        container.Register(c =>
                        new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve())
                        {
                            UseDistinctRoleTables = AppSettings.Get("UseDistinctRoleTables", true),
                        });
    How do I get to the IManage roles? I see i can override the IAuthRepository.

I found this link. But its not a replacement for Auth
[ServiceStack - roles and permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510905/servicestack-roles-and-permissions)

-_Edit 12/29 -- It is not calling the methods in MyOrmLiteAuthRepository. Do you know why?

AppHost.cs

```
            container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c =>
                new MyOrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>())
                {
                    UseDistinctRoleTables = AppSettings.Get("UseDistinctRoleTables", true),
                });


CustomAuthRepo
    public class MyOrmLiteAuthRepository : OrmLiteAuthRepository
    {
        public MyOrmLiteAuthRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory) : base(dbFactory) { }

        public MyOrmLiteAuthRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory, string namedConnnection = null)
            : base(dbFactory, namedConnnection)
        {
            DbFactory = dbFactory;
            NamedConnnection = namedConnnection;
        }

        public IDbConnectionFactory DbFactory { get; set; }
        public string NamedConnnection { get; set; }

        public override ICollection<string> GetPermissions(string userAuthId)
        {
            var permissions = base.GetPermissions(userAuthId);

            using (var ss = HostContext.ResolveService<SecurityService>(new BasicRequest()))
            {
                permissions = ss.UserPermissions(Convert.ToInt32(userAuthId));
            }

            return permissions;
        }


        public override bool HasPermission(string userAuthId, string permission)
        {
            var hasPermission = base.HasPermission(userAuthId, permission);

            using (var ss = HostContext.ResolveService<SecurityService>(new BasicRequest()))
            {
                hasPermission = ss.UserHasPermInRoleOrGroup(permission, Convert.ToInt32(userAuthId));
            }

            return hasPermission;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roles/Permissions work similar in that a User can have multiple Roles and Permissions but they're logically different in that a Role defines the Role a person has like "Employee", "Manager", etc and Permission defines functionality they have access to like "CanSubmitPurchaseOrders", "CanRefundCustomers", etc.

ServiceStack doesn't support Roles having permissions themselves but you can implement this functionality yourself in your own Custom AuthProvider by overriding `OnAuthenticated()` and populating the `Permissions` collections of `AuthUserSession` with a combination of all the permissions in all the Roles a User is in. If you're not using a custom AuthProvider you can modify the Users Session by implementing the `OnAuthenticated()` [Session of Auth Event Hooks](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#session-events).

Alternatively if you're using an AuthRepository like `OrmLiteAuthRepository` you can change how permissions are managed by overriding its [IManageRoles](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/IAuthRepository.cs) `GetPermissions()` and `HasPermission()` APIs to also inspect the Permissions that the Users Roles have assigned to them which you would need to maintain in an out-of-band table.

#### Overriding OrmLiteAuthRepository

OrmLiteAuthRepository implements `IManageRoles` so when needed you can cast `IAuthRepository` to `IManageRoles`, e.g:

```
var manageRoles = (IManageRoles)container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>();
```

You can override [OrmLiteAuthRepository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/Auth/OrmLiteAuthRepository.cs) and implement your own `GetPermissions()` and `HasPermission()` with normal inheritance, e.g:

```
public class MyOrmLiteAuthRepository : OrmLiteAuthRepository
{
    public MyOrmLiteAuthRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory) : base(dbFactory) { }

    public MyOrmLiteAuthRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory, string namedConnnection = null) 
        : base(dbFactory, namedConnnection) {}

    public override ICollection<string> GetPermissions(string userAuthId)
    {
        return base.GetPermissions(userAuthId);
    }

    public override bool HasPermission(string userAuthId, string permission)
    {
        return base.HasPermission(userAuthId, permission);
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question again. I am almost there now.

Comment: @SteveColeman can you please ask new questions in a new question instead of updating the existing one with new questions. What’s the exact question, what source code are you using that’s not calling your custom providers API?

Comment: I asked a new question. Sorry, i was extending this one since I had not solved the original query. I like to post all the code once its done online for everyone. In one place